# In web2py, can I have a template controller method, that can be used across views, just as for views, we have a layout that is extended by all views

Tags: web2py

I am trying to use a controller method that is used by the basic layout itself and I want this to work fine for all pages that extend this layout. Is there a way I can do that without repeating the method across all controllers on whose views the same is consumed? I can write it inside the layout view itself within the braces, but thought it would be clearer if it is inside a controller that just returns a variable to be consumed by the view.

Please comment if I did not make the question clear.

Comment: A "controller method" sounds like something defined in a controller, yet it sounds like you DON'T want to define it in a controller.  Maybe if you sketched out an example of what you are trying to accomplish, it would be clearer.

Comment: I actually want it inside a controller, but the method should be accessible by layout.html itself (I am using names that a default web2py project would create). Okay, for instance, there is a logic that sets a number of session variables in method in default.py after doing some db lookps. I want this to be used in views of other controllers as well, such as, say, settings.py etc. without writing the method once again on settings.py (OR) by writing the logic inside the view (layout.html) itself (which is how I am doing it currently and it has started getting messy).

Comment: You could place the code into a model. Since models by default are shared [across all controllers](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Workflow). Adding an extra model like 'shared_functions.py' would differentiate it a  little, and is easier to write then a standard module since it is automatically executed in the prepared environment web2py sets up for each request. If the code could be completely seperate from web2py requirements, like some encoding scheme, maybe that would the best choice.

Comment: Thank you so much! That helped! Can you post that as an answer itself so that it would get noticed better?

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the code you need, or most of it, inside a module, and have the appropriate view (layout.html?) call the function in the module?

Comment: It sounds like OP wants to call the method from the view, but I wouldn't swear to it.

Comment: @Scott Hunter - edited comment to reflect that possibility. Nevertheless, the solution may still be applicable: call a module method from the view (layout.html?).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Spokes. I did not get what you meant by module. You mean a method? Per my understanding, you can only call methods of the appropriate controllers in the views. layout.html (the basic template file which is extended by each of the views) does not have any controller associated with it and hence is the problem.

Comment: @rajaram_s - modules in web2py are no different from modules in python (i.e. libraries of functions/classes that you import: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html). Go to your "Edit application" page, and under views, you will find, "languages", then "static", then "modules." Create a new module file, put your code in there, import that code where necessary (i.e. perhaps in a model file, put " from [my_module] import * "), and call the function that you need in layout.html. The code doesn't have to be in the controller.

Comment: @rajaram_s - above, Remco suggests putting the function into a model (I cannot comment above due to insufficient reputation). This is not a good idea. First of all, models are there for DB definitions, not for defining arbitrary functions. Second, code in models is reloaded every time you load a page on your site. So, for efficiency, it is recommended that you actually move your database definitions to modules (yes, weird), [as the web2py book states](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/13/deployment-recipes?search=efficiency#Efficiency-tricks). As I said, modules are the way to go.

Comment: @rajaram_s - [from the web2py book](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/13/deployment-recipes?search=efficiency#Efficiency-tricks): "Minimize the code in models: do not define functions there, define functions in the controllers that need them or - even better - define functions in modules, import them and use those functions as needed."